# Cast Dictionary KeyCollection to String array

Tags: c#, .net, linq, c#-3.0, dictionary

I have a `Dictionary<int, string>` which I want to take the Key collection into a CSV string.

I planned to do:

```
String.Join(",", myDic.Keys.ToArray().Cast<string[]>());
```

The cast is failing though.

Thanks

Answer (score 13, accepted):

How about this...

```
String.Join(",", myDic.Keys.Select(o=>o.ToString()).ToArray());
```

Answer (score 8):

This will work:

```
String.Join(",", myDic.Keys.Select(i => i.ToString()).ToArray());
```

Answer (score 0):

Cast to a `string`, not a `string[]`

```
String.Join(",", myDic.Keys.ToArray().Cast<string>());
```

**Edit**: 
This does not work - Cast does not perform type conversion. There is a `ConvertAll` method on `Array` which is just for this purpose:

```
String.Join(",", Array.ConvertAll(myDic.Keys.ToArray(), i => i.ToString());
```